# Easiest way to add a DateCreated and DateModified field to an existing ASP.Net MVC 4.0 app with EF 4.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

Is there like some kind of base method I can tap into would that add DateTime.Now() when ever an EF entity is being created or updated?

I'm just wondering if there is a clever way to approach this without having to change every CRUD statement throughout the application.

Thanks.

Comment: Although there is no accepted answer here, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879011/entity-framework-sql2008-how-to-automatically-update-lastmodified-fields-for-e) has all the info you need. Override `SaveChanges` on your context and use `ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries()` to get the objects that have been modified.

Comment: Excellent. I'll look into that. Anything is better than having to manually add code into all my update and create statements.

Answer (score 1):

I've written up a blog post for any future visitors to this question. I use a base entity to add the columns to all entities and then override `SaveChanges()` to injects the times.

http://benjii.me/2014/03/track-created-and-modified-fields-automatically-with-entity-framework-code-first/

Comment: I will show all the 4 columns createby/on updatedBy/on on the views that it not good. because while updating a record person can change createdBy/on. and if you use 
`[Scafold(false)]`
as attribute on these 4 properties then when you edit earlier created model it will insert the null at the place of CreatedOn field..