# Optimistic mode concurrency with two fields in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

I'm using Entity Framework 4, C# and MSSQL Server 2008 R2. I know about the optimistic concurrency with rowversion, But I want to include two fields in concurrency. One is updated_date (datetime) and another is updated_by (string). For now I only can do it with updated_date concurrency mode fixed. What should I do to include updated_by also?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take reference at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592904.aspx) about optimistic pattern on EF. The EF have supported your scenario follow the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592677). With your scenario you can read original value of fields on object to validate it has been changed or not.

One more [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879011/entity-framework-sql2008-how-to-automatically-update-lastmodified-fields-for-e?rq=1) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/05/20/tip-19-how-to-use-optimistic-concurrency-in-the-entity-framework.aspx) to help you have one more approach to resolve your case.