# Entity Framework 6 Code First default datetime value on insert

Tags: c#, .net, sql, entity-framework

When I'm saving changes to the database, I'm running into the following exception:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Registered', table
'EIT.Enterprise.KMS.dbo.LicenseEntry'; column does not allow nulls.
INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.
```

The related code first model property looks like this:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), DataMember]
public DateTime         Registered          { get; private set; }
```

... and here's why I'm confused: As far as I know, by providing the annotation `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)` I'm ordering Entity Framework to auto-generate the field (in this case: Only once at creation time.)

So I'm expecting to have a non-nullable (required) field, without the possibility to alter the field manually where EF is taking care of.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Notes:

1. I don't want to use Fluent-API, as I want to use POCOs.
2. The property `defaultValueSql` is also not an option, because I need to rely database independed for this project (e.g. for `GETDATE()`).
3. I'm using Entity Framework 6 alpha 3, Code First.

Comment: Is the AutoGenerate also your Primary key? If so, you will need to specify the [key] annotation.

Comment: No. It's just a property.

Comment: I don't believe the DateTime data type has support for the identity field attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), DataMember]
public DateTime?            Registered          { get; private set; }
```

The question mark makes the property nullable

Comment: I tried your solution, but it doesn't seem like it's working, though it should. Whenever I generate an migration script, the field gets marked as "nullable: false" in the script. Even on database creation. What could be wrong? The private set?

Answer (score 2):

There is no default DateTime. Only a [min value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx).

You could potentially just set the datetime on that entity before calling     `dbContext.SaveChanges`.

[See this for a solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879011/entity-framework-sql2008-how-to-automatically-update-lastmodified-fields-for-e)

Answer (score 2):

This technique behaves like a `readonly` field that is persisted to the database. Once the value is set it cannot (easily) be changed by using code. (Of course, you change the setter to `public` or `internal` if needed.)

When you create a new instance of a class that uses this code `Registered` will not initially be set. The first time the value of `Registered` is requested it will see that it has not been assigned one and then default to `DateTime.Now`. You can change this to `DateTime.UTCNow` if needed.

When fetching one or more entities from the database, Entity Framework will set the value of `Registered`, including `private` setters like this.

```
private DateTime? registered;
[Required]
public DateTime Registered
{
    get
    {
        if (registered == null)
        {
            registered = DateTime.Now;
        }
        return registered.Value;
    }
    private set { registered = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did was I set value as optional and nullable. I used Data Annotation, but its also possible to use IsOptional in Fluent Api:

```
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
```

Then I created another Sql migration, to alter value to default:

```
    public partial class AlterTableUpdatedAtDefault : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            Sql(@"ALTER TABLE dbo.[Table]
                  ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Table_UpdatedAt
                  DEFAULT getdate() FOR UpdatedAt");
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            Sql(@"ALTER TABLE dbo.[Table]
                  drop CONSTRAINT DF_Table_UpdatedAt");
        }
    }
```