# Expose Private Setter in .Net Core 3.1 OData EDMModelBuilder

Tags: odata, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

How do you expose a property on a class that has a protected or private Setter with the EDMBuilder for .Net Core 3.1 OData.

For example:

```
public class Person
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; protected set; }
}

public class SomeClassToBuildEdmModel
{
   public static IEdmModel GetEdmModel( IServiceProvider serviceProvider )
   {
      var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder( serviceProvider );
      builder.EntitySet<Person>(nameof(Person)).EntityType.HasKey( e => e.Id );
   }
}
```

Performing a Get on the endpoint will only retrieve Id, not Name. The builder ignores any property that has a private or protected setter.

How do I override this or expose the property without removing the protected access modifier?

I did find this link:
[Old Solution to the Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43080216/odata-property-with-internal-setter-like-updatedate)

But since this answer is 2 years old, I was hoping for a more elegant or easier solution.

Update:
   I added:

```
public class SomeClassToBuildEdmModel
{
   public static IEdmModel GetEdmModel( IServiceProvider serviceProvider )
   {
      var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder( serviceProvider );
      var personConfig = builder.EntityType<Person>();
      personConfig.HasKey( e => e.PersonId );
      **personConfig.Property( e => e.Name ).IsOptional();**
      builder.EntitySet<Person>(nameof(Person));
   }
}
```

This seems to work. However, it seems hinky... is there a better way?