# Set default Date value during Model Generation in Code First Entity Framework Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am using VS 2013 C# Entity framework 6.0.0.0 Code First. I have Class like this below.

```
public class Om_Category
{
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; protected set; }
}
```

So far I am manually assigning the DateTime.Now value to this Property.

I found many articles on Google that only says to use Migration.

> Is there any way in EF Code First Fluent API with which we can set the
>   default value(getdate()) for CreationDate Column while model generation ?

Answer (score -1):

You can assign the property in the parameter less constructor.

I have done like this in the ctor of a root class .

Comment: Perhaps this is for you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879011/entity-framework-sql2008-how-to-automatically-update-lastmodified-fields-for-e](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879011/entity-framework-sql2008-how-to-automatically-update-lastmodified-fields-for-e)

Comment: And you will see there is no better solution, may be in another EF release.